# Is it safe to have a timer dispatch source scheduled every second?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have this timer created using GDC. It will call a method every 1 second. Is it safe to have this timer alive during the whole time, even in background?

```
self.theTimer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
    dispatch_source_set_timer(self.theTimer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (1.0) * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.theTimer, ^{
        [self awakeAndProcess];
    });

    // Start the timer
    dispatch_resume(self.theTimer);
```

The method "awakeAndProcess" has a "consumer" behavior where it checks a data queue and tries to send an HTTP request. So it is constantly checking if there are messages to be sent

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Generally speaking, constantly dispatching code from a timer is a bad practice.

Comment: It's not necessarily unsafe.. You don't state why you are doing this, though.

Comment: Sorry i edited the question

Comment: I don't think it unsafe, but it's extremely clumsy and unnecessary.

Comment: A consumer/producer solution would be more appropriate in such a situation.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off pausing the timer when going to background to conserve battery because the awakeAndProcess seems to be a network call. But if you are in background then all your tasks are suspended anyways so shouldn't be a problem. When in foreground its better to wait for the previous awakeAndProcess call to finish before you trigger the next call. Otherwise you might end up with lot of awakeAndProcess calls being batched together. If awakeAndProcess is not reentrant then it can cause havoc in your code. 
You are better off suspending the timer after the awakeAndProcess and then call resume after the awakeAndProcess is fully complete.

If you do this then its safe to use your approach.